# Js Filter nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, nested

Here is the code

```
let nestedArray = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6,7], [8,9,10]]
let arr = [2,3,6,7]
```

I want nestedArray filter all element equal arr element, then return

`result = [[2],[3],[6,7]]`

Here is my solution, it won't work.

```
arr.forEach(id => {
  let result = nestedArray.filter(nest => {
   return nest.filter(item => item === id)
})
```

Each time it only output a single match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let nestedArray = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6,7], [8,9,10]]
let arr = [2,3,6,7]
let result = nestedArray.map(array =>
  array.filter(item => arr.includes(item))
).filter((a) => a.length);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
nestedArray.map(
  na=>na.filter(
    num=>arr.includes(num)
  )
).filter(
  na=>na.length!==0
)
```